# How to group by nodes

Tags: prometheus

I'm doing a metric of % connection pool usage for mysql.

```
max_over_time(mysql_global_status_threads_connected[10m])/max_over_time(mysql_global_status_threads_connected[10m])
```

I have more 10 nodes, want to do over one metric, but for each server has its own line on the chart.
How to correctly make a grouping via node name?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sum()` aggregation function. You can read more about it [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators).

E.g.

Query: `sum by (nodeNameLabel)(yourQueryThatCalculatesUtilizationPercentages)`

Legend: `{{nodeNameLabel}}`